# Tough Question: How to Use "In The Lead"

Tags: idioms

Need some help on how to use "in the lead".  I came up with several possible valid usages.

Situation 1--  At a high school, two clubs, club A and club B, are trying to get as many students to join as possible.  Currently club A has enrolled more students than club B:

> Club A is ***in the lead***.

Situation 2-- A referendum will take place soon, concerning whether an geographical area currently part of a sovereign country, should become an independent sovereign country.  There are two political groups trying to influence voters.  The pro-union group want voters to vote no.  The pro-independence group want voters to vote yes.  A poll of like voters was recently done, and it shows that there more voters more likely to vote no than yes:

> The pro-union group is ***in the lead***.
>   The no vote is ***in the lead***.

Situation 3--  Suppose there is a soccer match between Team USA and Team France.
At the match are American fans supporting Team USA and French fans supporting Team France. Then, Team USA scored a goal, going up 1-0.  The American fans are very happy:

> The American fans are ***in the lead***.

Are the four sentences for respective situations (situation 2 has two sentences) okay English?

Comment: This seems to be a proofreading question. Could you add some details regarding why you think these usages might be OK or not, based on definitions or some other reference?

Comment: @user3169  This question is motivated by another question about "in the lead".

Comment: I don't think this is a proofreading question.  It does ask if the sentences are okay, but it has some rather detailed explanation of the OP's thinking and is focused on a specific point, usage of *in the lead*.

Comment: @snailboat  I am glad somebody sees the usefulness of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Used as a singular noun, we can certainly use *in the lead* that way. This said, your sentences ***in the given contexts*** are okay.

[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lead) talks about it:

> You often say that someone is in the lead.

This means that someone is winning, ahead or the like.

However, the last instance you describe does not talk about the American team winning the game. There, *in the lead* to mean *cheer/happy* is incorrect [Thanks user3169].

Comment: In Situation 3, the "American fans" are not in the lead. Its a competition between the teams, not their fans. You could say "The American fans are happy their team is in the lead."

Comment: Very good point. I was too tired to read all of them till end! :( Thanks. Editing.